# Confused over what self means in this method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, oop

I have the following code that **works** but Im slightly confused as to why.

```
before_save :generate_slug

def generate_slug
  self.slug = [id, title.to_url].join('-')
end
```

I was under the impression that using `self` on a model method would be a Class method whereas this information is clearly being saved to an Instance, is this correct?

If I remove `self` from the `self.slug` the method doesn't work and `slug` is `nil`.

So if I need `self.slug` for the method to work should be using `self` on `self.id` & `self.title.to_url` as well?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`self` in this case (within an instance method) refers to the actual instance object.

`self` in a method name (however) indicates the method is a Class method.

The `self.` is optional if you're referring to attributes, but is required when you're assigning attributes.

```
slug = [id, title.to_url].join('-')
```

creates a new local variable in the instance method

```
self.slug = [id, title.to_url].join('-')
```

updates the slug attribute of the object.

The reason you didn't need `self` for `id` or for `title` is because they weren't being assigned a value, just accessed, so the interpreter understands it has to get the model attributes.